# Get document name of embedded file in xls (Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, inputstream, hssf

I would like to save all embedded Files of a .xls (POI Type: HSSF) File, no matter which embedded filetype it is. So I'm happy if I can save all embedded files without extension. I'm using Apache POI Library 3.7 on Java 7.

Now, I'm having trouble using **createDocumentInputStream(document)**. I don't know how I can get this expected parameter. Can anyone help me?

```
public static void saveEmbeddedXLS(InputStream fis_param, String outputfile) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{
    //HSSF - XLS

    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Starting Embedded Search in xls...");

    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis_param);//create FileSystem using fileInputStream
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

    for (HSSFObjectData obj : workbook.getAllEmbeddedObjects()) {

        System.out.println("Objects : "+ obj.getOLE2ClassName());//the OLE2 Class Name of the object
        String oleName = obj.getOLE2ClassName();//Document Type

        DirectoryNode dn = (DirectoryNode) obj.getDirectory();//get Directory Node  


//Trying to create an input Stream with the embedded document, argument of createDocumentInputStream should be: String; Where/How can I get this correct parameter for the function?
        InputStream is = dn.createDocumentInputStream(oleName);//oleName = Document Type, but not it's name (Wrong!)

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfile + "_" + i);//Outputfilepath + Number

        IOUtils.copy(is, fos);//FileInputStream > FileOutput Stream (save File without extension)
        i++;
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? Also, does the [Apache Tika CLI tool in `-x` mode](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) (powered by Apache POI) give you what you need?

Comment: @Gagravarr My Code is part of a larger software, which also contains other features using apache poi. Apache POI is basically a part of Tika and I use POI because I don't need the other features of Tika. The reason I used the older version was, because some parts of my code don't work with the actual version. I'm now trying the same using  POI 3.14, but I have still the same problem. 
Please suggest a suitable solution. Thanks, Nicola

Comment: Try with the Apache Tika CLI. If that works, we can help you do the same thing with Apache POI directly. If it doesn't, then you're likely after information which isn't contained in the file

Comment: @Gagravarr Many thanks for your help, just saw that you're a apache developer. So I'm asking the right person. ;)
I tried now using the Tika CLI with -z Parameter and it works! But I haven't found any example source code yet. How can I implement this now in my code? (I can't use CLI statements in my software, so some example code for the same functionality as `-z --extract dir` would be fine) 
And just to know, is it even possible to store .doc files using only apache poi?

Comment: Well, Apache Tika is open source, so you can go read the code behind it! I'd suggest you have a quick read through the `handleEmbeddedOfficeDoc` method of [AbstractPOIFSExtractor](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java), then update your question with what you still need help on!

Comment: @Gagravarr I found the [ExtractEmbeddedFiles](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java) Tika example code, which works great. I didn't make any changes in the example code. I did now plenty of tests and had always the same problem. If there is a `.ppt` File (HSLF) embedded into any other file, Tika creates empty files. I always get every attachment, expect the .ppt content. 
Is there any known issue regarding this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: The `PPT` file format is "special", and does things differently to all of the other office file formats... See http://poi.apache.org/poifs/embeded.html#Files+embedded+in+PowerPoint for some hints

Comment: @Gagravarr So if it's special, how can I handle this using the [ExtractEmbeddedFiles](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java) Class? I wonder why it works using the Tika CLI. Can you give me any advice? I'm sorry if I'm asking troublesome questions, but I'm new to Java and don't know what I should do. Thanks for your help.